# CSS Affecting Every Other "Row" with Float Left "Cells"

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to redesign my blog's layout using CSS3.  Previously I used a table, but I never got it quite like I wanted.

The blog is called Wall of Text, and the header looks like a bunch of bricks (repeating background image).  Under it, are links to the archived posts, which are also intended to look like bricks of the header wall.  The first row looks great, but when the links wrap, the next row should have a left offset/margin/padding of 20px in order to maintain the brick-like pattern.

[image]

The arrow shows where I want it indented.

I was hoping I could make the container `display: table-row` use the `:nth-child(even)` selector.  However, setting it to table-row made positioning hard, and I ended up making it `display: table`.  Then, as it's currently set up, the `:nth-child(even)` selects every other brick rather than every other row.

Here's a link to my code populated with static dummy "links": [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bk3qz5s1/).

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Are you accepting a javascript based solution? I see no way in which this could be solved using pure CSS. We can use the `:first-line` pseudo element, but I'm sure you have more than 2 lines of these bricks.

Comment: Sure, I'd use javascript/jquery.

Comment: Is the number of bricks per row a constant or does it depend on screen width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First step** is to determine where new lines begin. If all the bricks have identical width, you can calculate the amount of bricks per line if you also know the sum width of all bricks, and that of the container.

**Javascript code**

```
// width of bricks container
var cont_width = document.getElementsByClassName('bricks')[0].offsetWidth;

// width of all bricks
var bricks_width = 0;
var bricks = document.getElementsByClassName('brick');

for (var i = 0; i < bricks.length; i++) {
    bricks_width += bricks[i].offsetWidth;
}
```

**Second step** is to add some margin (negative maybe?) to every second line's first element. In the above code snippet we have all the brick elements in `var bricks`, and we can iterate over those once again, something like this:

**Javascript code**

```
var bricksPerLine = Math.floor(bricks.length / (bricks_width / cont_width));
var bAlt = false;

for (var i = 0; i < bricks.length; i++) {
    if (i % bricksPerLine == 0) {
        if (!bAlt) {
            bAlt = true;
            bricks[i].style.marginLeft = '-20px'
        } else {
            bAlt = false;
        }
    }
}
```

[JS-Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bk3qz5s1/4/)

---

**Note**: If your website uses a responsive design, you need to call this code on every resize. Also, as you may see, the code can be optimized in several spots.